# Json loads is saying this is an invalid JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7

```
[
    {
        "category_id": "",
        "ad_type": "offer",
        "price": "1000",
        "sale_by": "owner",
        "title": "Test title",
        "description": "",
        "location": "washington",
        "postal_code": "1001",
        "address": "",
        "images": [
            "User/Desktop/image1.jpg",
            "User/Desktop/image2.jpg"
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to get `json.loads()` to read a file containing the chunk of text above, and parse it into an array of dictionaries containing the info above. However when I try to run it it just says

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

But copying and pasting this into http://jsonlint.com/ says that it's a valid JSON so I'm not sure what's wrong..

This is my code:

```
with open(source_data) as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
```

Comment: The data is fine, so the problem must be in how you are reading it.  Please post your code.

Comment: What you've pasted here works fine with `json.loads` meaning you're passing something else. How are you reading the file?

Comment: Can you please show your python code? `json.loads` is for a string, not a file object

Comment: I have updated my code in the main post

Comment: What does `print(data_file.read())` give you…?

Comment: I fixed it, turns out for some reason I added a comma after the array for images...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that it is a string.

```
a = '''[
    {
        "category_id": "",
        "ad_type": "offer",
        "price": "1000",
        "sale_by": "owner",
        "title": "Test title",
        "description": "",
        "location": "washington",
        "postal_code": "1001",
        "address": "",
        "images": [
            "User/Desktop/image1.jpg",
            "User/Desktop/image2.jpg"
        ]
    }
]'''
```

output:

```
json.loads(a)
[{u'description': u'', u'title': u'Test title', u'price': u'1000', u'ad_type': u'offer', u'sale_by': u'owner', u'location': u'washington', u'address': u'', u'images': [u'User/Desktop/image1.jpg', u'User/Desktop/image2.jpg'], u'postal_code': u'1001', u'category_id': u''}]
```